# How to upload image to server with high resolution Using Base64?

Tags: android, image

Here, i have problem with image uploading using base64 with high resolution.
When i uploading any high resolution image to server that is uploaded successfully but the resolution get by server is only near 135*240 but actually i was uploaded 1920*1080. So i want to get this resolution or not at list 135*240.

Comment: Post your code for more info

Comment: http://notepad.cc/imageUploadMethod

Comment: hello any way to achieve this

Comment: Is this "your" server or someone else's?  Could the server be auto-resizing to 135x240 (for example, as some do when uploading avatar pictures)?

Comment: no server code not resize this image, so problem is android size.

Comment: Replace 
`b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos); with  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);`

Comment: Could not get any different..

Comment: Please post complete code here. You are of course uploading a thumbnail instead of the original image.